# jni binding, javac error, unexpected token

Tags: java, console, java-native-interface, token, openvr

We did an [openvr](https://github.com/java-graphics/openvr) java binding using jna and it's true what they usually say about jna, it's quite easy to implement.

On the contrary, it has some performance penalties. Googling around and reading some papers, jna is from 10 to almost 80 times slower than jni ([here](https://www.mitre.org/sites/default/files/publications/13-3234_Mixing-C-and-Java-for-High-Performance-Computing.pdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175163/1047713)).

This wouldn't be a problem for not-critical performance scenarios, but we run into some performance issues and we are trying to addresses all the causes, such as the binding for example.

I searched for some time and there are a lot of different ways to achieve this, but given the header we'd like to port is relatively easy (last famous words..) we are trying to do it manually.

I started by the [two most important calls](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L3319-L3351), `VR_Init` and `VR_ShutDown`:

```
inline IVRSystem *VR_Init( EVRInitError *peError, EVRApplicationType eApplicationType )
{
    IVRSystem *pVRSystem = nullptr;

    EVRInitError eError;
    VRToken() = VR_InitInternal( &eError, eApplicationType );
    COpenVRContext &ctx = OpenVRInternal_ModuleContext();
    ctx.Clear();

    if ( eError == VRInitError_None )
    {
        if ( VR_IsInterfaceVersionValid( IVRSystem_Version ) )
        {
            pVRSystem = VRSystem();
        }
        else
        {
            VR_ShutdownInternal();
            eError = VRInitError_Init_InterfaceNotFound;
        }
    }

    if ( peError )
        *peError = eError;
    return pVRSystem;
}

/** unloads vrclient.dll. Any interface pointers from the interface are
* invalid after this point */
inline void VR_Shutdown()
{
    VR_ShutdownInternal();
}
```

The corresponding [java class](https://github.com/elect86/test/blob/master/Test/src/test/HelloVr.java) is pretty simple:

```
public class HelloVr {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("openvr_api");
    }

    static final int VRInitError_None = 0, VRApplication_Scene = 1;

    public native IVRSystem VR_Init(ByteBuffer peError, int eApplicationType);

    public native void VR_Shutdown();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloVr();
    }

    public HelloVr() {

        ByteBuffer peError = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        IVRSystem hmd = VR_Init(peError, VRApplication_Scene);

        System.out.println("error: " + peError.getInt(0));
    }

    class IVRSystem {

        private long nativePtr = 0L;
    }
}
```

Now is time to compile `HelloVr.java` into `HelloVr.class` by typing

> javac HelloVr.java

But I get `Unexpected Token`:

```
PS C:\Users\GBarbieri\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test\Test\src\test> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javac.exe"
.\HelloVr.java
Unerwartetes Token ".\HelloVr.java" im Ausdruck oder in der Anweisung.
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:66
+ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javac.exe" .\HelloVr.java <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (.\HelloVr.java:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the ideal answer I was looking for, but it made it working.

I added the `javac.exe` directly to the `PATH` environment variable and simply run:

```
javac HelloVr.java
```